# How to convert EJS Template's table column's strings in dd-mm-yyyy Formats?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs, embedded-javascript

I am rendering through `EJS template` like this and `table data` coming from `Database`

```
<td><%= Patient.StudyDate %></td>
```

`Patient.StudyDate`  is a `string` and rendering as `20181029` (first `4` is a year then `2` is a month and last `2` is a day so I want to change this `string` to `dd-mm-yyyy`) and it's coming from  Database

[image]

I want to show that like this `29-10-2018`

How to do that in EJS  templating language?

Comment: What type `Patient.StudyDate` is? It's `string`, `number`, `Date`?

Comment: its a string Coming From Database like 20181029

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<td><%= Patient.StudyDate.toString().replace(/^(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})$/, '$3-$2-$1')%></td>
```

Use regexp to match days, month and year and put it in correct order

```js
// Patient.StudyDate.replace(/^(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})$/, '$3-$2-$1');
console.log('20181029'.replace(/^(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})$/, '$3-$2-$1'));
```

Comment: <td><%= Patient.StudyDate.replace(/^(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})$/, '$3-$2-$1')%></td> is giving error Patient.StudyDate.replace is not a function

Comment: So `Patient.StudyDate` is no a `string`